# Building OSMBright for imposm returns python json error

Tags: python, json, imposm

I'm trying to execute "./make.py" as part of the OSMBright.xml generation (following this document: https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/ , but for imposm instead of osm2pgsql).

I changed config["importer"] to imposm in configure.py. Executing "./configure.py" is running fine. Then I try to execute "./make.py" and gets this error:

```
[root@myserver osm-bright-master]# ./make.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./make.py", line 128, in <module>
    build()
  File "./make.py", line 41, in build
    template = loads(templatefile.read())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 319, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 336, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self._scanner.iterscan(s, **kw).next()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/scanner.py", line 55, in iterscan
    rval, next_pos = action(m, context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 183, in JSONObject
    value, end = iterscan(s, idx=end, context=context).next()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/scanner.py", line 55, in iterscan
    rval, next_pos = action(m, context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 217, in JSONArray
    value, end = iterscan(s, idx=end, context=context).next()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/scanner.py", line 55, in iterscan
    rval, next_pos = action(m, context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 183, in JSONObject
    value, end = iterscan(s, idx=end, context=context).next()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/scanner.py", line 55, in iterscan
    rval, next_pos = action(m, context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 198, in JSONObject
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting property name", s, end - 1))
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 555 column 7 (char 26783)
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution myself. The problem is a stray comma in the `osm-bright.imposm.mml` json file. I pasted the json in an online json validator. This showed me the error:

```
Error:Invalid comma, expecting }.[Code 141, Structure 1908]
    "extent":"-20037508.34 -20037508.34 20037508.34 20037508.34",

     },
```

After removing the illegal comma at the end of line 553:

```
    "extent":"-20037508.34 -20037508.34 20037508.34 20037508.34"

     },
```

I could execute it successfully.